# how to change languages on onclick in php?

Tags: php

I have  input type button and  having onclick() functionality,when I click once it shows  "en" inside the button and  I click again need to show "ml" inside the button

Comment: yea I need the code.I have no Idea.so i didnt do anything @Dagon

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service, we will help you with code you have written, but YOU have to start

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: Thanks @MatthewCliatt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the jquery .html() fucntion to change the content

Comment: but I need to display two different languages

Comment: That you have to pass as an argument and change the html according to that